# adding a number to numbers in a sentence or a topic

Tags: numbers, sum, sentence

I have a sentence (i may use a topic) like this:

George (98) Michael (65) Jim (53)... and so on.

I want a code in any programming language which add one (+1) to the numbers so the result comes as:
George (99) Michael (66) Jim (54)

I perhaps use arabic letters instead of english.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, if you want to find increment just the numbers in the string you can just call:

```
string.gsub(/(\d{1,})/) { |num| (num.next) }
```

This will find all the numbers in the string and increment them.  Hope this helps